# Ebean on duplicate key update

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

is there anyway to do an 'on duplicate entry update' for an ebean save? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to do it in your controller ie. while binding form from request

```
 ...
Some some = form().bindFromRequest().get();
if (some.id == null){
    some.save();
} else {
    some.update(some.id)
}
```

That way the statement will be working on all DB engines not only these which has the mentioned feature.

Additionally you can do the trick in the model by overriding `save()` and `update()` of the `Model` class

Comment: Thanks biesior. Btw, big fan of your comp sci solutions, been running into them all over the web and have helped me a lot.